# Scrapy spider doesn't release items memory

Tags: python, xml, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm using scrapy to extract some data from various sources, and it works really well
but now I have written a spider to extract data from a big XML file (about 100MB => 40000 items).

I'm using the scrapy [XMLFeedSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#xmlfeedspider).

The problem is scrapy is using a lot of memory (1GB or more) and I don't know why it doesn't release the memomry used by my items.

When I use the trackrefs tool of scrapy (to connect to my spider with telnet) I get the following output:

```
  >>> prefs()
  Libxml2Document                     2   oldest: 160s ago
  CustomName                          1   oldest: 163s ago
  XmlResponse                         1   oldest: 161s ago
  XmlXPathSelector                    1   oldest: 0s ago
  Request                             1   oldest: 163s ago
  CustomName                          38893   oldest: 150s ago
```

I have disabled all the item pipelines.

In my spider I don't keep any reference of items, I just create items and return them.
I can't find where is the memory leaks ...

Is there an explanation why my items are not released?

Comment: Scrapy doesn't accumulate items in memory and when it does it is considered a bug, check your spider-middlewares just in case the generator returned by XMLFeedSpider is consumed into a list. It is much simpler if you can show your project code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the output of "prefs", its first column is class name, and Scrapy has no class named "CustomName". This name looks like some column in XML field. Further more, have you see these strange two lines:

```
CustomName                          1   oldest: 163s ago
CustomName                          38893   oldest: 150s ago
```

It means "different classes, but with same name". You should post your code. I guess your Item  class just named "CustomName".